# Criar Listener para vários CheckBoxes gerados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Problema:

Preciso Armazenar o valor de vários Checkboxes que estão marcados, eles são gerados dinamicamente pela API portanto não possuem um Id fixo, apenas um value e um "nome"

Como eu estou fazendo atualmente:

```
<script>

            let arrayItens = []

            function atualizaArrayItens(value){

                //Se o array já tem o item, retira do array
                if(arrayItens.includes(value)){
                    arrayItens.pop(value)
                    console.log(arrayItens)
                //Se o item não está presente no array, adicione    
                }else{
                    arrayItens.push(value)
                    console.log(arrayItens)
                }

            }

            function enviarDados(){
                //Criar objeto para enviar via POST
                let dadosParaEnviar = {
                    NomeCliente: document.getElementById("nomeCliente").value,
                    ItensComprados: arrayItens
                }
                //Enviar dadosParaEnviar via POST
                console.log(dadosParaEnviar)
            }

        </script>

        <span id="checkBoxes">

            Lista de Compras:<br/><br/>

            Nome do Cliente: <input type="text" id="nomeCliente"><br>

            <input type="checkbox" value="1" onchange="atualizaArrayItens(this.value);">Maçã<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" onchange="atualizaArrayItens(this.value);">Banana<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" onchange="atualizaArrayItens(this.value);">Pêra<br>
            <input type="checkbox" value="4" onchange="atualizaArrayItens(this.value);">Uva<br>

            <input type="button" value="Salvar" onclick="enviarDados();"><br>

</span>
```

Deste modo a função atualizaArrayItens é chamada cada vez que um checkbox é clicado, existe uma maneira mais eficiente de realizar essa tarefa?

Comment: o que você quer fazer é simplesmente adicionar o `atualizaArrayItens(this,value)` num evento de onchange para todos os checkboxes gerados dinamicamente?

Comment: Basicamente sim, Ao invés de ficar colocando ' onchange="atualizaArrayItens(this.value);"' em todos os checkbox checar todos que estao marcados dentro do span e pegar o value deles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando o seletor `"#checkBoxes [type=checkbox]:checked"` com `document.querySelectorAll` você irá pegar todos os checkboxes marcados. Depois fazendo um `for...of` você adiciona os valores na array, e você pode fazer tudo isso na função `enviarDados()`, e não precisa dos vários `onchange` nos elementos e nem de duas funções:

```js
function enviarDados(){
   
   let arrayItens = []
   let itens = document.querySelectorAll("#checkBoxes [type=checkbox]:checked")

   for(let item of itens) arrayItens.push(item.value)
   
    //Criar objeto para enviar via POST
    let dadosParaEnviar = {
        NomeCliente: document.getElementById("nomeCliente").value,
        ItensComprados: arrayItens
    }
    //Enviar dadosParaEnviar via POST
    console.log(dadosParaEnviar)
}
```

```html
<span id="checkBoxes">
   Lista de Compras:<br/><br/>
   
   Nome do Cliente: <input type="text" id="nomeCliente"><br>
   
   <input type="checkbox" value="1">Maçã<br>
   <input type="checkbox" value="2">Banana<br>
   <input type="checkbox" value="3">Pêra<br>
   <input type="checkbox" value="4">Uva<br>
   
   <input type="button" value="Salvar" onclick="enviarDados();"><br>
</span>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado era exatamente o que eu queria!

Answer (score 2):

Se você deseja simplesmente adicionar um evento em todos os seus checkboxes, pode usar o código abaixo:

```js
var cbs = document.querySelectorAll('#checkBoxes > input[type="checkbox"]');

cbs.forEach(function(cb) {
  cb.addEventListener('change', function() { atualizaArrayItens(this.value) });
})

function atualizaArrayItens(value){
  alert('trigger');
  //substitua isso com a sua função de atualização
}
```

```html
<span id="checkBoxes">
    Lista de Compras:<br/><br/>

    Nome do Cliente: <input type="text" id="nomeCliente"><br>

    <input type="checkbox" value="1">Maçã<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="2">Banana<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="3">Pêra<br>
    <input type="checkbox" value="4">Uva<br>

    <input type="button" value="Salvar" onclick="enviarDados();"><br>
</spam>
```

Coloquei um alert no lugar da função para você poder ver funcionando, mas é só substituir o interior da função e irá funcionar normalmente, não importa quantas checkboxes sejam criadas, desde que dentro deste spam.